# How do I get rid of these blue squares

Tags: html

I added an a tag so these images could be links and it added those weird blue things showed up. how do I get rid of them?

[image]

my code looks like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.github.com/example" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/Icons/github.png" alt="Github" >
</a>
<a href="https://example.itch.io" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/Icons/itchio.png" alt="Itch.io">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be a good idea to give those link tags a class name like the following and then target them:

```
<a href="https://www.github.com/example" class="social-links" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/Icons/github.png" alt="Github" >
</a>
<a href="https://example.itch.io" class="social-links" target="_blank">
   <img src="images/Icons/itchio.png" alt="Itch.io">
</a>
```

Then in your css do this:

```
a.social-links {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to remove the underline for the anchors (that browsers display by default).

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file add text-decoration: none; to your anchor tags

Like so:

```css
a { 
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I bet that will fix it.